# What is safest way to set password for new Azure Active Directory B2C user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am looking at the following lines of code from [this sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/blob/master/Graph-ASPNET-46-Snippets/Microsoft%20Graph%20ASPNET%20Snippets/Models/UsersService.cs), where an Azure Active Directory B2C user is being created:

```
// Add the user.
User user = await graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = Resource.User + guid.Substring(0, 8),
    MailNickname = alias,
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        Password = Resource.Prop_Password
    },
    UserPrincipalName = alias + "@" + domain
});
```

What is `Resource`? How do I use it to generate a `Prop_Password` like the code here is doing? Is this the safest way to generate and apply a password for a newly created user? If not, what is the safest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sample code reads the password value from [a resources file](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/blob/a78f907c892c13c65004a6097735ac5c66b6b799/Graph-ASPNET-46-Snippets/Microsoft%20Graph%20ASPNET%20Snippets/App_GlobalResources/Resource.resx#L436).

I recommend you use a password generator, such as [CodeBits.PasswordGenerator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CodeBits.PasswordGenerator), to generate a unique, strong, random password for each new user.